# The graph topologies for powersets

Tags: gn.general-topology, function-spaces

Given a topological space $X$ and a metric space $(Y,d_Y)$, there are a number of topologies one may put on the space $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$. Perhaps the most famous among these are the [**pointwise convergence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence#Topology), [**compact-open**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology), and **uniform** topologies. Since the introduction of these topologies, however, a number of other function space topologies have been studied, including the **fine** and **graph** topologies. We now recall their definitions (including that of the uniform topology for context):

- The **uniform topology** is defined as the topology generated by the basis $\{B_{d_Y}(f,\epsilon)\ |\ f\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\text{ and }\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\}$, where
  $$B_{d_Y}(f,\epsilon)\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\{g\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\ |\ d_Y(f(x),g(x))<\epsilon\}.$$
- The **fine topology** is defined as the topology generated by the basis $\{B_{d_Y}(f,\epsilon)\ |\ f\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\text{ and }\epsilon\in\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R}_{>0})\}$, where
  $$B_{d_Y}(f,\epsilon)\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\{g\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\ |\ \text{for each $x\in X$, we have $d_Y(f(x),g(x))<\epsilon(x)$}\}.$$
  Note that here we have allowed $\epsilon$ to be a function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, instead of just a constant real number.
- The **graph topology** is defined as the topology generated by the basis $\{B_{d_Y}(f,\ell)\}_{(f,\ell)\in I}$, where:

  - $f$ is a continuous function from $X$ to $Y$;
  - $\ell$ is a lower semicontinuous function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$;
  - $B_{d_Y}(f,\epsilon)$ is given by
    $$B_{d_Y}(f,\epsilon)\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\{g\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\ |\ \text{for each $x\in X$, we have $d_Y(f(x),g(x))<\epsilon(x)$}\}.$$

These topologies are all comparable, and satisfy the following relations:
$$\mathcal{T}_{\text{pointwise convergence}}\subset\mathcal{T}_{\text{compact-open}}\subset\mathcal{T}_{\text{uniform}}\subset\mathcal{T}_{\text{fine}}\subset\mathcal{T}_{\text{graph}}.$$

Now, the graph topology can in fact be (and was originally) defined by a different basis, which works for $Y$ an arbitrary topological space, given by
$$\{\langle U\rangle\ |\ U\in\mathrm{Open}(X\times Y)\}$$
with
$$\langle U\rangle\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\{f\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\ |\ \mathrm{Gr}(f)\subset U\},$$
where $\mathrm{Gr}(f)\subset X\times Y$ denotes the graph of $f$. One can also replace $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ in this definition with the set $Y^X$ of all maps from $X$ to $Y$ (continuous or not) to obtain a topology on $Y^X$.

---

**The question, finally:** Specialising to the case where $X$ is an arbitrary topological space and $Y$ is the set $\{0,1\}$ topologised with either the discrete, Sierpiński, or indiscrete topologies, we may consider the graph topology on the set $2^X\cong\mathcal{P}(X)$. Is it known how the resulting three graph topologies compare with the other commonly used powerset topologies for $\mathcal{P}(X)$, like the Vietoris topology?

(Incidentally, one result I know in this direction is the one mentioned in the introduction of the book [*Function Spaces with Uniform, Fine and Graph Topologies* by McCoy–Kundu–Jindal](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-77054-3), which states that the subspace topology on $\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R})$ induced by the Vietoris topology on $\mathrm{Cld}(X\times\mathbb{R})$ agrees with the graph topology on $\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R})$.)